# Golang dispatch same data to go routins

Tags: go, mutex, race-condition, channel

There is one go routine generating data. Also are many go routines that handles http response. I want generated data to be passed to all http handler routines. All dispatched data are same.
I thought two solutions. Using channel pipeline to fan-out or using mutex and condition variable.
I concern if former way needs memory allocation to put data in channel.

What should I choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use case sounds like it benefits from channels. In general channels are preferred when communication between go routines is needed. Sounds like a classic example of a [worker pool](https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools).

Mutexes are used to protect a piece of memory, so only 1 goroutine can access/modify it at a time. Often times this is the opposite of what people want, which is to parallelize execution.

A good rule of thumb is to not worry about optimization(memory allocation or not) until it actually becomes an issue. Premature optimization is a common anti-pattern.

Comment: Thank you. As your answer, I decided to use channels. That's what go is made for.. You thaught me a lesson :)